# Warning em aplicação ReactJS com Vite e TypeScript

Tags: react, typescript, warnings

Boa tarde estou desenvolvendo um site em ReactJS para aprendizado na tecnologia, e estou recebendo um warning no meu terminal com a seguinte mensagem:

[vite] warning: Top-level "this" will be replaced with undefined since this file is an ECMAScript module
9  |      lineNumber: 6,
10 |      columnNumber: 15
11 |    }, this),
|       ^
12 |    cName: 'nav-text'
13 |  }, {

Plugin: vite:esbuild
File: C:/Users/muril/Documents/Projetos/documentation-site reactjs/src/components/NavBar/SideBarData.tsx

O código deste arquivo está logo abaixo:

```
import { FaHome, FaUserAlt, FaCode, FaPhoneAlt } from 'react-icons/fa'
export const SideBarData = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        path: '/',
        icon: <FaHome />,
        cName: 'nav-text',
    },
    {
        title: 'Sobre',
        path: '/sobre',
        icon: <FaUserAlt />,
        cName: 'nav-text',
    },
    {
        title: 'Projetos',
        path: '/projetos',
        icon: <FaCode />,
        cName: 'nav-text',
    },
    {
        title: 'Contato',
        path: '/contato',
        icon: <FaPhoneAlt />,
        cName: 'nav-text',
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque o plugin-react usa @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx para transformar o JSX.

Para uma solução alternativa, você pode definir esbuild.logOverride para omitir o aviso.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  esbuild: {
    logOverride: { 'this-is-undefined-in-esm': 'silent' }
  }
})
```

Conforme a sugestão: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8644#issuecomment-1159308803